# How to get the cursor back on the last line of a file

Tags: bash, files

I have a `text file with three numbers and each number separated by new line.

```
-55
-56
-64
```

When I open the file I can see the cursor is on the fourth blank line.

[image]

I want the cursor to stay on the last number of the last line.

[image]

I tried some things with `sed` like that :

```
sed -i '${/^$/d}' troisignaux.txt
```

but without success

Is there a way some bash command can do that ?

Thanks

Comment: What's the output of `hexdump -C troissignaux.txt`?

Comment: `sed -i '${/^$/d}'` would remove the last line if it's empty (which sounds like is what you want here) with the GNU implementation of `sed`. What implementation of `sed` does your system have?

Comment: When you say you're opening the file, what are you opening it with? A text editor? Which text editor?

Comment: It's also possible that your `troisignaux.txt` file have Microsoft Windows CRLF delimiters instead of `LF`, which `hexdump -C` should reveal. Then running `dos2unix` on it before that `sed` command would fix that and other issues often found with Microsoft files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have determined that your file ends with a newline character, just remove that last byte, e.g. using `head -c-1 troisignaux.txt > temp.txt; mv temp.txt troisignaux.txt`.

Note that I really can't find a single use case where what you're doing is a *good* idea. You're breaking the systematic structure of your file: it's always a number followed by a newline.

Note that it's even sometimes enforced by coding standards that the last line should end with a newline; that's both for structure, as well as for safety when concatenating files: you can always just concatenate two files where every line ends with a newline, but if you concatenate a number (say, 32) to your file after you removed the final newline, it will end in the number `-6432`.

Comment: That work's ! Thanks for your help and explanation

Comment: You can remove the last byte of a file with `truncate -s-1 file` (with GNU truncate) without needing a temp file or to read the file.

Comment: @OP: What text editor are you using? Vim doesn't "add" empty lines to text files like that. Most Unix (or Unix-like) utilities follow POSIX definition of [Text Files](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403), as _characters organized into zero or more lines,_ while the [_Lines_](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206) always end with the newline character. Some utilities will issue warnings or even won't work correctly if the last character in a "Text File" (as per this definition) is not a newline.

Answer (score 0):

There is no fourth blank line. This is how your text editor shows there is a newline character at the end of the third line, by placing the cursor on the fourth line. For instance VS Code behaves like this. Another editor, e.g. VIM, will place the cursor on the third line and not show a fourth line.
With VS Code you can delete the newline on the third line with a simple backspace. VIM will not do that and will add a newline if there isn't one on the last line when you save the file.

A solution is use a different text editor.